# How to fetch parent and child comment at single query?

Tags: php

I have this table structure

I want to build query through which i can fetch all the rows using tst_id (which is called parent comment) and this tst_id  should be matched with (if any) parent_tst_id  (these are called child comments) .BUT the condition is parent comment(parent_tst_id=0) and child comment (tst_id) should be fetch at the same time and in same query.

```
tst_id  mem_id  from_id      testimonial       added            parent_tst_id   
3500    822     822     and KdevInd      1316613536         3497
3499    329     329     Reply by me      1316613489         3497
3498    821     821     a Fan comme      1316613307         3497
3497    329     399     Profile COm      1316613243         0
```

please help,
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can self-join the table

```
SELECT child.*, parent.*
FROM comments AS child
LEFT JOIN comments AS parent ON child.parent_tst_id = parent.tst_id
WHERE child.tst_id = XXX
```

Comment: but I dont have `tst_id` I have only `mem_id` of parent comment

Comment: `WHERE parent.mem_id = XXX` in that case. Though in this case you'd get any child comments that have that XXX record as their parent.

Comment: no Mark , its not like that see table I printed in question I have only `mem_id=329` in parent comment I may comment on my parent comment and different users can also comment that parent comment so `mem_id` is different each time

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `tst_id` available with you is always that of a parent comment, you can simply use the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM comments
WHERE tst_id  = XXX
OR parent_tst_id = XXX
```

Comment: no i dont have `tst_id` I have only `mem_id` of parent comment

Comment: So do you want to retrieve all the parent comments made by a certain mem_id along with their child comments?

Comment: yes u not got my point , so thats why I have in table `tst_id` as child comment in `parent_tst_id`